# Xpath query with multiple nodes at different levels

Tags: xml, xpath, xpathquery

I need a Xpath query to find a XML file with certain nodes. The nodes are located at different levels in the XML file, under different parents. So, it would be like if I want to recover a file like the one below using the nodes "author" and "ref year =1999".

```
<FILE>
    <header>
        <author> X </author>
    </header>
    <text>
        <type>
            <ref year="1999">
        </type>
    </text>
</FILE>
```

The only difference is that the XML I'm using have a much more complex structure, so it would be ideal if I could use a "//" to find the nodes anywhere, instead of using the exact path.
I can't use the | operator to join the two nodes, because I want to find the files which satisfy both conditions and not only one.

Thanks!

Comment: So what is your desired output? `FILE` matched by two specific descendants?

Comment: This is a well-expressed first question.  To make it even better as @Andersson suggests, include an example complex enough to cover what should and what should not be selected, and list your desired output explicitly.  I believe I've anticipated what you need, and have answered below, but such details will help you get on-the-mark answers sooner in the future.   Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//FILE[header/author="X" and text/type/ref/@year="1999"]
```

will select `FILE` elements anywhere in the document that meet the conditions in the predicate.

Use `or` rather than `and` if you want a disjunctive predicate.  (Note that `|` is used to concatenate node sets.)  Combinations of `and`, `or`, and `not()` can be used to express full boolean expressions in the predicate.

If the structure beneath `FILE` itself varies, you can use `.//` to "skip over" the variations.  For example,

```
//FILE[.//author="X" and .//ref/@year="1999"]
```

will disregard the path between `FILE` and each of `author` and `ref/@year`.